# Case statement with where condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to write a CASE statement in SQL.

The DB structure is as follows:

```
==============================================
tender_id  |  file_no  |   subject
==============================================

150001         16/41        Against Shipment
150005         16/42        Pending
150008         16/43        Shipment Clause
1500081        16/43        NULL or Empty
1500082        16/43        NULL or Empty
==============================================
```

I am trying to write a CASE statement which shows the subject. The criteria is if Subject is `NULL or EMPTY` then it should fetch the subject where subject is entered with the criteria `where file_no = file_no`. In this case tender_id 1500081 and 1500082 should take the subject as 'Shipment Clause' since the file_no of those matches.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you provide the complete SQL statement that is failing?

Comment: If you express it in the form of an SQL fiddle, it might help you to get your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.tender_id, t2.file_no,
  CASE t1.subject 
  WHEN 'NULL or Empty' THEN t2.subject 
  ELSE t1.subject END AS subject
FROM YourTableName AS t1
JOIN YourTableName AS t2 
  ON (t2.file_no = t1.file_no AND t2.subject <> 'Null or Empty');
```

This assumes there is only one row where the subject is set, for each file_no.

Update: I created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b8ed/1) to demo this query. This satisfies the problem you described, as I understand it.

Comment: For some reason its not working. I am checking the reason.

Comment: i have updated the question with what i have tried. can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c38f93/10)

I have assumed first two column to be `int` you can change it according to your database and edit accordingly.

Assuming you will always have `file_no` in the table you search by `file_no` always which will give you the desired result

```
SELECT subject
FROM [table_name]
WHERE file_no = (SELECT file_no FROM [table_name] where tender_id = [required_tender_id])
AND subject IS NOT NULL;
```