# Operand should contain only 1 column in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Iam getting an error when i run this query. The error states that 'Operand should contain only 1 column' .Can anyone help me on this?

```
SELECT
tender_id,
customer_code,
contact_person,
po_number,

(SELECT t1.tender_id, t2.file_no,
  CASE t1.tech_analyst 
  WHEN 'NULL or Empty' THEN t2.tech_analyst 
  ELSE t1.tech_analyst END AS tech_analyst
FROM view_sales_report AS t1
JOIN view_sales_report AS t2 
  ON (t2.file_no = t1.file_no AND t2.tech_analyst <> 'Null or Empty') LIMIT 1) as tech_analyst,

view_sales_report.category

FROM view_sales_report
ORDER BY tender_id DESC
```

Comment: You can't select multiple columns in the subquery like that. Infact your logic seems wrong to me. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Can u pls check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390604/case-statement-with-where-condition-in-sql/

Comment: Iam trying to write a CASE statement inside mysql query.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please show sample input and output.

Comment: Hi Tim. My actual issue is this. I am struck up with writing a CASE statement. This error is in continuation with that. Can u pls check this link. This is the actual problem iam facing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390604/case-statement-with-where-condition-in-sql

Comment: What is wrong with Bill Karwin's answer?  You should not have posted again.

Comment: It was not working for me, that's why posted again.

Comment: Anyways, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple column in sub query is not allowed

try to use something like this to achieve your result..

```
   SELECT
   T1.PrimaryKey,
T1.SomeColumn,
MySubQuery.Col1,
MySubQuery.Col2,
MySubQuery.Col3
    From
Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 Col1, Col2, Col3, Fkey FROM Table 2 ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS MySubQuery ON T1.PrimaryKey = MySubQuery.Fkey
```

Comment: this is SQL server syntax (TOP)